# How to identify the main global object for Vanilla Picker?

Tags: javascript

[Vanilla Picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vanilla-picker) is an absolutely fantastic color picker ([example one](https://codepen.io/Sphinxxxx/pen/zRmKBX), [example two](https://codepen.io/Sphinxxxx/pen/vzWexy)). However the [documentation](https://vanilla-picker.js.org/gen/Picker.html) is a bit lacking. I know how to initialize though I don't know how to identify whatever global object (besides `Picker`) so I do not know how to access the `show()`, `hide()` and/or `movePopup(options, open)` methods.

The code I've come up with below at least *prevents additional popups* beyond one-per-element. However it would make more sense (and waste less memory) to simply use the `movePopup()` method though again I do not know what parent object to refer to. If I `console.log(Picker);` and looking through the events in the inspector tools of Waterfox and Chrome has me a bit lost. I also have to click *twice* initially for the popup to be displayed.

How do I identify the global / primary object which I can then use `movePopup` to only initialize a single `Picker` with Vanilla Picker?

No frameworks or libraries, except of course of Vanilla Picker itself.

**JavaScript**

```
// See URL for Vanilla Picker code:
// https://unpkg.com/vanilla-picker@2.8.0/dist/vanilla-picker.min.js

window.onclick = function(event)
{
 if (event.target.hasAttribute('data-color') && event.target.getAttribute('data-color')[0] == '#')
 {
  console.log(event.target.getAttribute('data-color'));
  var picker = new Picker({alpha : true,
  color: event.target.getAttribute('data-color'),
  editor : true,
  editorFormat : 'rgb',
  onChange: function(color)
  {
   event.target.setAttribute('data-color',color.rgbaString);
   event.target.style.backgroundColor = color.rgbaString; console.log(color);
  },
  //onDone: function(color) {console.log(color);},
  parent : event.target,
  //popup : 'bottom'
  });
 }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div data-color="#f00" id="color1">Color 1</div>
<div data-color="#0f0" id="color2">Color 2</div>
<div data-color="#00f" id="color3">Color 3</div>
```

Comment: var picker = new Picker <- the lower case written `picker` is your global object. You might need to define the variable out of window.open first though e.g. `var picker;` and then inside window.open `picker = new Picker...`

Comment: @obscure I did not try it though alas those methods are not available after declaring a `var picker = new Picker()` and inspecting the new `picker` object.

Comment: Trust me it's there. ;) I don't knnow what browser you're using but in FireFox it's listed under <prototype>: {…}

Comment: @obscure `var picker = new Picker()` and then `picker.__proto__.movePopup`. Now I just have to figure out how to utilize the method correctly. Thank you. I'll post the answer once I figure it out...presuming I figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you instantiate an instance of Picker you assign it to a variable you can reference it through. If this variable is defined in the global scope, you can access this instance and thus all of its methods from anywhere in your code.

Here's a simple example, where we re-use the same Picker for two different DIVs:

```js
var picker = new Picker();

function changePicker(e) {
  picker.movePopup({
    parent: e.currentTarget
  }, true);
}
document.getElementById("divA").addEventListener("click", changePicker);
document.getElementById("divB").addEventListener("click", changePicker);
picker.onDone = function(color) {
  this.settings.parent.style.backgroundColor = color.rgbaString;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vanilla-picker@2.8.0/dist/vanilla-picker.min.js"></script>
<div id="divA">TestA</div>
<div id="divB">TestB</div>
```

This will set backgroundColor of a DIV as soon as the done button of the picker is pressed. If you take a look at the onDone callback function, you'll notice `this.settings`. This is an object returned by the picker itself. Among other things it returns the HTML element which is currently associated with the picker - `this.settings.parent`.

Comment: I was getting close though I just don't have enough experience to pick up on some of the subtleties of how other people sometimes program. Brilliant! You have my sincere gratitude!

Comment: Hehe, thanks for the kind words. You're welcome! =)